# Регулярные выражения Sublime

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в csv файле:

```
"Кулачковый переключатель двухпозиционный 0-1, 3 фазы, 16А.";"0-1.jpg:image/jpeg:34506";"0-1_thumb1_thumb2.jpeg:jpeg:8131:244/264/0-1_thumb1_thumb2_9.jpeg";"0-1_thumb1.jpeg:jpeg:8131:244/264/0-1_thumb1_9.jpeg";"PSA016AK331S";
```

При помощи регулярных выражений нужно изменить на:

```
"Кулачковый переключатель двухпозиционный 0-1, 3 фазы, 16А.";"0-1.jpg:image/jpeg:34506";"http://mysite.ru/244/264/0-1_thumb1_thumb2_9.jpeg";"http://mysite.ru/244/264/0-1_thumb1_9.jpeg";"PSA016AK331S";
```

Т.е `"0-1_thumb1_thumb2.jpeg:jpeg:8131:244/264/0-1_thumb1_thumb2_9.jpeg"`        => `"htt://mysite.ru/244/264/0-1_thumb1_thumb2_9.jpeg"`

Какое выражение нужно для этого использовать?

Имена файлов и папок может быть разное (244/264/0-1_thumb1_thumb2_9.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помоглo такое РВ

```
(?<=jpeg";").*:(?=[\w]+\b\/\b[\w]+\b\/\b[\w]+\.jpeg")
```